# Issue with Multiple renderAjax Forms Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, ajaxform

I am rendering ajax form

```
  public function actionUser()
{

    $model = new UserInfoForm();
    $model->user_id = $this->user->id;
    $validation = $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(null !== $validation){
        return $validation;
    }

    $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;
    return $this->renderAjax('user.php',[
            'error' => $error,
            'user'  => $user,
            'model' => $model
            ]);

}
```

And in user.php, i am having following line to get all user companies and jobs

```
 <a href="<?= Url::to(['user/details', 'id' => $user_id]) ?>">Show User Companies and Jobs</a>
```

Now in user details action

```
public function actiondetails()
    {

        $model = new UserJobsForm();
        $validation = $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(null !== $validation){
            return $validation;
        }

        $companies = Companies::getUserCompanies();
        $jobs =  BlogPost::getUserJobs();

        return $this->renderAjax('user_info.php',[
                'error' => $error,
                'model' => $model,
                'companies' => $companies,
                'jobs' => $jobs
        ]);

    }
```

In my user_info.php view page, i am able to see all the details. I am also seeing user.php view page, this is because, i am rendering user_info page on top of user.php. My requirement is not to open in new page. so i am trying to render on top of user.php. I want to close user.php as soon as user_info.php rendered. How can i do this??

Comment: Give more informations and add the views and controller code.

Comment: @stfsngue i edited my question with controller and view

Comment: Are you rendering user.php and user_info.php in a modal dialog?

Comment: yes, and second modal dialog is just displaying on first modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to close another modal, you can call the script below in the user_info view

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
       $('#id_of_user_modal').modal('hide');
    });

</script>
```